# Creating an async consumable object in Node

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js

### Background

I have a situation where I have fixed number of objects with their own routines that would need to be called with the same initial message.

To accomplish this, I have a Factory that binds objects to a Composite object whose main method is to call methods on its subordinates without having to know how many it has.

This routine is to be called upon receiving a message from a queue, the client to that queue is responsible for initiating that procedure.

### Code/ Question

Just to keep the code looking succinct, here are the individual modules for completeness.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// module1/index.js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

function A () {}

A.prototype.method = function(msg, cb) {
  console.log('A class: %j', msg );
  cb(null, 'done message');
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// module2/index.js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

function B () {}

B.prototype.method = function(msg, cb) {
  console.log('B scraper: %j', msg);
  cb(null, 'done message');
};
```

Here is the factory that has the job of knowing what it imports and attaching the objects defined above to the Factory's caller:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// - factory.js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

var A = require('./module1');
var B = require('./module2');

function Factory () {
  var o = Object.create(null);
  o.obj1 = new A();
  o.object2 = new B();
  return o;
}
```

Now here's the part that is in question. The `method` method does some 'clever' stuff to make something that the async library can understand and use. This code runs, and it about as efficient as it needs to be but I would like to ask if there is another, more readable way to build an object for use in `async.parallel()`.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// - composite.js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
var async = require('async');

function Composite () {
  this.objects = new Factory();

}

Composite.prototype.method = function(msg) {
  var self = this;
  var enum = Object.keys(this.objects);
  var newObj = {};
  // for each member-name in the obj.
  enum.forEach(function (name) {
    // put a function in the newObj
    newObj[name] = function (callback) {
      // who calls the object's method with some initial values
      // and a callback
      self.objects[name].method(msg, function(err, results){

        if (err) { callback(err); }
        callback(null, results);

      });

    };
  });
  // actually do something
  async.parallel(
    newObj,
    function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
  });
};


module.exports = Composite;
```

This is just here for extra context.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// RMQ Client
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
var Composite = require('./composite');
var Client = {};

Client.on('message', startJob, msg)

function startJob (msg) {
  var comp = new Composite();
  comp.method(msg);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error that needs to be handled correctly:

```
      self.objects[name].method(msg, function(err, results){

        if (err) { 
           return callback(err); 
        }
        return callback(null, results);

      });
```

You need to return the callback on the error, otherwise if an error comes down, you will hit both callbacks.